# Bootstrap 3: Navbar not full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to create a Navbar with 100% width in Bootstrap, but it isn't working like it should.
How can I scale the Navbar to 100% width?

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border: 1px solid">  
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootflat</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isih9.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code looks fine as per your requirements.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid">  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div>
      <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootflat</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Please see [here](http://www.bootply.com/131127)

Answer (score 8):

Remove `.row` and `.col-md-12` divs – they add padding. You only need to use them when you divide content in columns.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the row and the grid col divs since the navbar will be at a full width at all times and you are using `.container-fluid`. Try this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootflat</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

As happened to me, if you want it with the full width on the top (sticky). Adding `fixed-top` class to the `nav` will do.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following css code `body{padding:0;margin:0}`. It worked for me.

Hope this helps.